# How to allow method to access number twice

Tags: java, methods

Im having a hard time getting the balance to stay updated when i call the withdraw/deposit methods. im asking how i can store a number and keep so i can keep updating it with several method calls to it.

here is the main code snippet

```
public void savingsWithdraw(){
    System.out.print("Enter withdraw amount: ");
    Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
    double amount = w.nextDouble();
    Savings with = new Savings();
    with.withdraw(amount);
    System.out.println("Savings Balance is: " + with.getBalance());
    mainMenu();
}
```

here is the sub class

```
public class Savings
 {
    double balance =0;
    public void deposit(double amount){
      balance=balance+amount;
 }
    public void withdraw(double amount){
      balance=balance-amount;
 }
    public double getBalance(){
      return balance;
  }
```

}

Comment: Don't create a new `Savings` object each time the method is called. You have multiple options, you can have a global `Savings` object, a class member/field `Savings` object or have the method take a `Savings` object as a parameter (I wouldn't use this method).

Comment: Also note: You're going to no doubt run in to unexplainable errors if you create a new `Scanner` with `System.in` on each call. You should instead use a global `Scanner` or add a `Scanner` parameter to the method and pass in a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Savings with = new Savings();
```

This line pretty much indicates that a new Savings object is being created everytime the savingsWithdraw() method is being called, thus causing the balance to always stay at zero. Try making one object of Savings outside the method and then only make calls with that Savings object.

OR a better design might look like this:

```
public void savingsWithdraw(Savings account){
    System.out.print("Enter withdraw amount: ");
    Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
    double amount = w.nextDouble();
    account.withdraw(amount);
    System.out.println("Savings Balance is: " + account.getBalance());
    mainMenu();
}
```

This still eliminates the recreation of a Savings object everytime you call that function.

Answer (score 0):

As both @Jurko and @Jonny as stated; you create a new Savings object with the line

```
Savings with = new Savings();
```

Each Savings object is going to have their own `double balance` which means if you create a Saving object, deposit 500, that object will have 500 of whatever the balance currency is. Then you create another object, the balance of that one will be 0.

It can easily be solved by having one single object to work with all the time, instead of creating an instance every deposit/withdraw.

Another very easy solution, if you want to stick with object creation, which isn't recommended performance wise though. Make your balance variable static, like this:

```
static double balance = 0;
```

That way all the Savings objects will share the same balance variable, in short.

Also a tip is to close the Scanner afterwards to avoid memory leak:

```
w.close();
```